# Creating cache shall I use file system or the memory?

Tags: java, caching, memcached

I have millions of rows to be read from database and multiple users come in a day to read the same data. so I want to create a cache. so that I don't have to go to database  again for same data.

I have seen many option but couldn't find figure out which approach to use.

Creating my own cache I am thinking saving the data of a query result and writing in a file or

use some third party in memory caches?
Guava CacheBuilder ,LRUMap caching,whirlycache ,cache4j.

Comment: "Best" entirely depends upon your requirements.

Comment: This you can only answer yourself. It depends how often there will be a cache hit, size of data, size of main memory. etc. Start by making a statistic how often the same query is called

Comment: data could be millions of records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not the first person to have requirements like this, which is why there are dozens of cache implementations available as open source projects, and even a standard set of Java APIs for caching (JCache). If your needs go beyond those solutions, there are even commercial solutions that handle tens of terabytes of data transparently across RAM, flash, database, etc. If none of those are sufficient, then you should definitely write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Its totally dependent on multiple factors. and i think answer will be based on environment, Size of data etc. here is the main points

1. You want to keep the cache in ram as much as possible because its faster to access than being in file system.
2. You can also use OS memory mapped files which does balance access vs utilization. I suggest any proven solution than creating your own

If you are running low on memory then you might need to ask question on what is more important like caching the top access data as they are most likely to be asked by client.

So there is not a sure or definite answer but you have to decide based on your constraints. Hope  this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overengineering the problem, it isn't trivial to write a performant, transparent cache, unless you only need a simple HashMap to hold some values. You should focus on writing code to solve your domain problem and not writing too much framework code.

Stop reinventing the wheel, use either an in-memory cache (e.g. infinispan or redis) or a database (e.g. postgres). You will have less pain and better performance.